# How to download BibTex raw dataset for deep learning (LSTM )?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, dataset, lstm

I am trying to test my model on the benchmark text classification dataset "Bibtex". The Bibtex dataset is available in tf-idf vectors but LSTM works on sequences. Bag of Words is a vectorized representation of text as a vector of counts. Therefore, it is no longer a sequence of words. RNN takes sequences as an input.

How can I download the raw data of Bibtex for custom feature extraction?